# chain controller functions/code in sequential order and handle errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have some controller functions for different tasks which may call service functions (which in turn contain $http requests). Ex:

```
// this should be run first
function getData1(request) {
    dataService.getData1(request).then(function success(response) {
        return response;
    })
};

// this should run after getData1()
function getData2(request) {
    dataService.getData2(request).then(function success(response) {
        return response;
    })
};
```

I am calling these functions from a central place on a certain event (say, when user changes the input/request data):

```
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.$watch('input', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue !== oldValue) {
        request = newValue;
        $scope.data1 = getData1(request);
        $scope.data2 = getData2(request);
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
});
```

But as far as I know, the `getData1()` and `getData2()` make asynchronous requests and it might cause `$scope.loading = false` before the data is loaded.

Also, if there are any errors in one or more requests, the `$scope.data1` or `$scope.data2` variables will have the rejected Promise values, right?

So, what are the 'best practices' to chain such functions and also handle errors if there are any? Please help.

Comment: You can make a callback chain, i.e call getData2() inside the callback of getData1(). This is the most simple way. However for more complicated uses, you can think of using promise.

Comment: I don't want to use the callback chains. It makes getData2() call dependent on getData1(). I want to separate the concerns i.e. control such chaining from a central place.

Comment: If you dont want to use callback, you can try using promise, or some es6 features such as async/await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getData1 and getData2` (which in turn calls `$http`) returns `promise`.

```
var promise1 = dataService.getData1(request);
var promise2 = dataService.getData2(request);
```

you can use `$q.all()`. Pass `promise1` and `promise2` to `$q.all`.This does not guarantee that promise will resolve in sequence.

```
If one promise fails, the combined promise fails.
If all promises succeed, the combined promise succeeds.
```

[example link for $q.all](http://www.ryansouthgate.com/2016/04/19/q-all-combining-promises-in-angularjs-2/)

For sequential execution,

```
dataService.getData1(request1).then(function(response1) {
    //do your stuff
    return dataService.getData2(request2);
}).then(function(response2) {
    //response2 - response of dataService.getData2(request2)
    //do your stuff
}).catch(function(error) {
    //on error if any of this fails.
})
```

Comment: I am not returning a promise from getData1(). To return a promise, I would have to do `return     dataService.getData1(request).then(function success(response) {
        return response;
    })`.

Comment: But I need to call the controller function `getData1()` and `getData2()` in sequence. Because there are other tasks I want to do in between these calls. I want to put the data fetching operations in separate functions so that I can also easily unit test them. Putting them in variables `promise1` and `promise2` does not solve the problem of sequential calls.